# How to append Properties to an XML tag from a same named tag in the same XML file using C#

Tags: c#, xml

I am very confused about adding properties to an XML Tag from a same named tag at other location from the same xml file at runtime using C#.

The xml file looks like this - 
"Sample.xml"

```
<university>
  <college>
    <name> Something </name>
    <estd.> Something </estd.>
  </college>
</university>
```

I have another code somewhere else in the **same xml file** - "Sample.xml"

```
<Deemed>
  <college>
     <affiliated> something </affiliated>
     <year> something </year>
  </college>
</Deemed>
```

Now what i want to do is to is to get the data of college tag, from these two different parent tags, into a single variable using C#.

It should be like this -

```
College data  = //Get data from Xml loaded into this object ;
```

The Properties of "**data**" should be **name, estd., affiliated** and **year** all loaded from the same xml file.

I should be able to access data.name, data.estd, data.affiliated and data.year altogether.

I tried many combinations loading this XML data into the variable but could not do so.

It loaded all properties from the university tag to the variable and then when i loaded data again it replaced those properties with properties from the deemed tag.

Can anyone help????

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements aren't terribly clear, but you could use LINQ to XML like this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("data.xml");
Dictionary<string, string> collegeSubelements = doc.Descendants("college")
   .Elements()
   .ToDictionary(x => x.Name.LocalName, x => (string) x);
```

That will create a dictionary with keys of "name", "estd.", "affiliated", "year" and the corresponding values. That's assuming you want *all* college elements within the document, of course.